# Coherence Near cache with Distributed back scheme and local storage settings

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

I use Coherence 12.1.2.0.0

The topology of my system is: three nodes with application (cache clients) and separated cache server with large amount of memory.

My goal is to create caching system which is not fully depended on cache server and at the same time consumes strict memory on application servers. So I want to store all values that were ever put to cache on cache server. But if cache server doesn't work applications can still operate with their small local caches.

I thought that Near cache is that I need. It consists of local-scheme as front and distributed cache as back scheme. But when I set local-storage setting to false in distributed section on clients I can't operate even with front local cache as I get "No local storage enabled node exists" error for every put operation. If I set local-storage to true and limit local storage memory for example to 1 unit cache server doesn't receive placed values from client side. More precisely it receives some of them but not all of them. For example if I do "put 1 1" and get it several times and after that try "put 2 2" and "put 4 4" I never get "2 2" and "4 4" together on cache server. In that case cache server contain "1 1" and may be one of values "2 2" or "4 4" but never all three pairs at the same time.

I tried backing-map-scheme with direct local scheme and read-write-backing-map-scheme with local scheme in internal section. The result is the same. This is my approximate test config:

```
    <near-scheme>
        <scheme-name>near</scheme-name>
        <front-scheme>
            <local-scheme>
                <scheme-ref>local</scheme-ref>
            </local-scheme>
        </front-scheme>
        <back-scheme>
            <distributed-scheme>
                <scheme-ref>distributed</scheme-ref>
            </distributed-scheme>
        </back-scheme>
        <invalidation-strategy>all</invalidation-strategy>
    </near-scheme>

    <distributed-scheme>
        <scheme-name>distributed</scheme-name>
        <service-name>DistributedCache</service-name>
        <local-storage>false</local-storage>
        <backing-map-scheme>
          <local-scheme>
            <scheme-ref>local-binary</scheme-ref>
          </local-scheme>
        </backing-map-scheme>
        <autostart>true</autostart>
    </distributed-scheme>

    <local-scheme>
        <scheme-name>local</scheme-name>
        <eviction-policy>HYBRID</eviction-policy>
        <high-units>1</high-units>
        <unit-calculator>FIXED</unit-calculator>
        <expiry-delay>{expiry 1h}</expiry-delay>
    </local-scheme>

    <local-scheme>
        <scheme-name>local-binary</scheme-name>
        <eviction-policy>HYBRID</eviction-policy>
        <high-units>300</high-units>
        <unit-calculator>BINARY</unit-calculator>
        <expiry-delay>{expiry 1h}</expiry-delay>
    </local-scheme>
```

What set of schemes do I need?

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're trying to use doesn't exist. Oracle Coherence allows you to define a near cache into your application side, but it have to be supported by the far cache server. Without it you can't save anything. The client side near cache requires it server side for interact as  a big DB for loading and updating the data received from the application.
The trick you are trying for set 1 unit only is wrong as well. Each client side is trying to update the values by themselves. The issue here is that when client side 'A' sends an update while 'B' sends as well, one of the is received before (you don't know which) and the other is marked as invalid. And then, if you have in cache 1 1, 'A' sends 2 2 and 'B' 3 3, one of them (i.e. 3 3) will remain and 2 2 will be marked as invalid as 1 1 was in an hypothetical side 'C'.
You are abusing the capability of the near cache - It was not designated for that. Coherence is a reliable cache and then if server side doesn't work, you app will not as well.
If you need near caches to be sometimes updated with a remote server (sounds like this) consider using another solution.
Hope I helped you.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already got this mistake. If I use distributed cache the values spread among the cluster considering that all nodes should have approximately the same amount of data. So my current question is how to tell the coherence that nodes in my cluster aren't equal. One of them should contain 90-95% amount of data and others nodes 3-5% for each of them. I think it's possible via my own classes for key-partitioning and key-assosiator settings. But it's wrong way I think. Do you know easy way to say "this node should contain 90% of data of whole cluster"?

Comment: Also I thought that overflow scheme can resolve my problem, but it doesn't support distributed scheme as back-side. It's strange. I assume that my goal is the common but not so specific. I have server with a lot of memory for caching everything and I need to store quick small data on client side.

Comment: You need to define the tag `<backup-storage>`. inside this tag you can set the `<initial-size>` and `<maximum-size>` elements.

Comment: Thanks. But these attributes can be used only for off-heap and file-mapped backup types. And I want to use on-heap but with size limitation on each node.

Answer (score 0):

Lost your actual question. But if you want to allocate/restrict different memory size for different nodes in a same cluster, then you can set the unit-calculator to Binary then provide the custom max memory size via JVM parameter while starting the cluster node. 
Check how to calculate the size of object in cache.

[Implementing Storeage Node](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHDG/cache_back.htm)

Comment: Thx. But it seems it isn't what I need. If node that was selected for storing value doesn't have enough memory this value displaces another value or it wouldn't be stored.

Comment: Could you post your actual question again, it may help to get proper answers. got lost somewhere in the chain of comments.